# lxml can not import etree package

Tags: python

I am using Macosx high sierra and python 2.7 version. I found the following error when i want to import lxml.etree

```
import lxml.etree as et
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 68, in init lxml.etree
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

Comment: Which Python2.7 are you using, the system's or the one installed by Homebrew? Are you using a virtualenv? How did you install lxml and what version? How did you run the script?

Comment: I can't reproduce on macOS High Sierra, python 2.7.16 (Homebrew), lxml 4.4.1.